# Finding sub-strings between two characters

Tags: python, string

I want `(202, 233)` and `(286, 298)` from the following string as separate two substrings.

```
x = "[977, 1, 0, (202, 233), (286, 298)]"
```

What I tried till now is given below

```
char1 = '('
char2 = ')'
substr1 = x[x.find(char1) : x.find(char2)]
```

It gives me output as `(202, 23` which is not the same as required. Also I am not able to find the second substring using this way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the example you provide, `x` is not actually a string, but a list of integers and tuples - did you forget the quotes around the string? In what situation do you need to get these sub-strings? Are you extracting information from some other Python file? Because if so, there's far better ways of doing so.

Comment: @Grismar My bad, I forgot to put quotes in the given string. Edited. I am extracting the information in the same file. Thanks for pointing out that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following.

```
import re
print(re.findall('\(.*?\)', x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have to worry about nested parentheses, you could try using `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "x = [977, 1, 0, (202, 233), (286, 298)]"
matches = re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['(202, 233)', '(286, 298)']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
import re
print(re.findall('\(.*?\)', x))
```

Or use:

```
import ast
print([str(i) for i in ast.literal_eval(x) if isinstance(i, tuple)])
```

Both output:

```
['(202, 233)', '(286, 298)']
```

Answer (score 0):

Input is String:

```
    x = "[977, 1, 0, (202, 233), (286, 298)]"
```

Output Expected:

```
   (202, 233), (286, 298)
```

Using ast.literal_eval,  the string can be made as Python List. 
After converting it to a pythonic object, inspection on datatype can be done to isolate tuples.

**Trial**:

```
    x_as_string = """[977, 1, 0, (202, 233), (286, 298)]"""
    x_as_list = ast.literal_eval(x_as_string)

    expected_output = []

    for i in x_as_list:
        if isinstance(i,tuple):
            expected_output.append(i)

    print(str(expected_output))
    print(''.join([str(e) for e in expected_output]))
```

Reference : [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 0):

A very naive approach to this problem (without regex) is

```
start = -1
end = -1
ans = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == '(':
        start = i
    elif x[i] == ')':
        end = i
    if (start != -1 and end != -1):
        s = x[start:end + 1]
        if not s in ans and s != '':
            ans.append(s)
```

The above approach is string based. It extracts the substring from '(' index to ')' index.

A better approach than this is

```
x = eval(x)
for i in x:
    if type(i) is tuple:
        print (i)
```